# Search for a particular string using grep

Tags: grep

I wanted to search for this particular string secure="false" in my folder. But when I use a normal grep function grep -r "secure="false"" it gives me no results.

Comment: Try `grep -iFr 'secure="false"' .`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your string: `grep -r "secure=\"false\""`